# TCPClient TwitchBot The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request

Tags: c#, .net-core, chatbot, tcpclient, twitch

I made a Twitch chat bot based on this example: https://medium.com/swlh/writing-a-twitch-bot-from-scratch-in-c-f59d9fed10f3

It works great except for one small exception that occurs usually when I first run the application for the first time every day:
***Exception Type**: System.IO.IOException

**Exception Message**: Unable to read data from the transport connection: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request..

**Stack Trace**:    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.GetResult(Int16 token)

at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReadAsyncInternal[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Memory`1 buffer)

at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBufferAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)

at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadLineAsyncInternal()

at ChatBot.Start()

**Additional Info**: System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.*

I can get around the issue by just looking for this error and then restarting the app but in a real-time environment, I'd like to avoid having to restart the application anytime this happens.

For reference, this is built into my .NET Core 5 Windows Forms app.

```
public async Task Start()
        {
            try
            {
                tcpClient = new TcpClient();
                await tcpClient.ConnectAsync(ip, port);
                SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(tcpClient.GetStream(), false, ValidateServerCertificate, null);
                await sslStream.AuthenticateAsClientAsync(ip);

                streamReader = new StreamReader(sslStream);
                streamWriter = new StreamWriter(sslStream) { NewLine = "\r\n", AutoFlush = true };

                await streamWriter.WriteLineAsync($"PASS {password}");
                await streamWriter.WriteLineAsync($"NICK {nick}");
                IsStarted.SetResult(true);

                System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(async delegate (object unused)
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        string line = await streamReader.ReadLineAsync();
                        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
                        {
                            if (line.EndsWith("Welcome, GLHF!"))
                                IsConnected.SetResult(true);

                            if (line.StartsWith("PING"))
                            {
                                string[] split = line.Split(" ");
                                await streamWriter.WriteLineAsync($"PONG {split[1]}");
                            }
                            else if (line.StartsWith("@badge-info") && (line.Contains("PRIVMSG") || line.Contains("msg-id=submysterygift")))
                            {
                                if (Properties.Settings.Default.DEBUG_MODE)
                                    logger.Info(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(line));

                                TwitchChatMessage msg = GetTwitchMessage(line);
                                OnMessage(this, msg);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (Properties.Settings.Default.DEBUG_MODE)
                                    logger.Info(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(line));
                            }
                        }
                        else
                            OnError?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                    }
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Error(ex);

                if (!Dashboard.IsFormClosing)
                {
                    if (ex.Message.Contains("The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request"))
                        OnRestartNeeded?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                    else
                        OnError?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                }
            }
        }
```

It seems to throw the error when it hits:
string line = await streamReader.ReadLineAsync();

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

TIA

Comment: Not sure, maybe you need to set a KeepAlive? You are definitely missing `using` in various places to dispose the client, stream, reader and writer, although that is not the cause of your current issue it may casue other problems. You should also use `Task.Run` rather than `QueueUserWorkItem`, also note that the `catch` does not cover the lambda with the `while` loop.